# from script import function runs everything?

Tags: python, python-import

Say I have a script script.py:

```
class Something():
   def __init__():
      self.value = 3

s = Something()

def function1():
   return 'Hello World'
```

If I go into a jupyter notebook and run `from script import function1`, why does that run the `s = Something()` part? I know that running `import script` would result in [everything in the script being run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788190/when-importing-a-function-it-runs-the-whole-script) so I understand that, but I thought that `from script import function1` wouldn't run the whole script.

Comment: The module is run in it's entirety no matter how it is imported. An import statement (both variations) just get the module from `sys.modules`, if the module is not in `sys.modules` it is run and inserted into `sys.modules`

Comment: This is covered in the top answer of the question you linked: *"This holds no matter if you do `import module` or `from module import function`, as these do the same. Only the final assignment is different ..."*

Comment: Whoops that's my mistake, I missed that. Thanks all for the responses. I marked the question as similar as suggested by another user... or I can just delete it if that's better?

Comment: @piedpiper No worries! I'd say, don't bother deleting it unless you start getting downvotes.