# How to properly import two files within the same pycharm project?

Tags: python, pycharm

First of all, please keep in mind I'm no python expert, barely even beyond a beginner.

I have this project in pycharm with multiple files (simply for easier navigation/orginisation), and in one, I'm trying to link to a defined print in another file using "from FILENAME import DEFNAME". But whenever I run the file, it runs the second file first, when it should be running parts of the first file. It doesn't even just run the imported def from the 2nd file, it starts from the very beginning of it.

I wrote it originally about a month ago and left it since then, I swear it worked fine last time, how can I prevent file1 from automatically running file2 in its entireity first while also still being able to call on a def from it?

(Removing the "import" line in file1 fixes it, but also isn't helpful at all lol)

Comment: Python will run any code in a imported file that isn't in a class, function or "main" (there are probably other exceptions too) when importing.

Answer (score -1):

It's simply the normal behavior of Python. When you import a function from a file it will run the whole file. Let's put it in an example:

**First File**

```
print("This will run First")
def modified_print():
    print("This will run Third")
print("This will run Second")
```

**Second File**

```
from first_file import modified_print
if __name__ == '__main__':
    modified_print()
```

**Result**

```
This will run First
This will run Second
This will run Third
```

You can refer to this question for more details [When importing a function it runs the whole script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788190/when-importing-a-function-it-runs-the-whole-script)